# Android In App Billing check if test purchase

Tags: android, in-app-purchase, in-app-billing

I'm testing Android In App Purchase.

I followed google's example and every purchase (either test and real purchase) was successful.

But I should know if the purchase was testing or a real purchase.

Is there any Android method or API that checks it?

Thanks for your answer

Answer (score 0):

You can check out on the Google Play dev console for the purchase you did under the Order Management section. The test ones will have a "Test" keyword in the front as is in the example below.

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your answer. But I want to know if it was a test purchase in Android code.